# Unable to position well to center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to position a well to the center of the page. There are similiar questions on SO, but the code is somewhat different to mine. My HTML is given below:

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="well col-sm-4" align="center">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <p><h2>Login</h2></p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group text-center">   
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password">
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Forgot password</button>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <p>Don't have an account yet? <a>Create one now</a></p>
                        </div>
                     </form>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried putting the well div inside another div with col-md-12 and other values, but the well did not get centered. Does anyone know how I could center the well in the page?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could put two dummy divs to make your well centered. I have noticed that you only have one `col-sm-4`

Try this:

```
<div class = "col-sm-4"></div>
<div class = "well col-sm-4">
<!-- your content here -->
</div>
<div class = "col-sm-4"></div>
```

In that way you can have your `well` centered.

You can also do this

```
<div class = "well col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<!-- content here -->
</div>
```

To make your well centered on desktop view 1280px and above.

Answer (score 4):

You could try [offsetting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

Give your columns the class `col-sm-offset-4`

Like so: `<div class="well col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/u48v34p7/

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 well col-sm-offset-4" align="center">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <p><h2>Login</h2></p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group text-center">   
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group text-center">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password">
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Forgot password</button>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <p>Don't have an account yet? <a>Create one now</a></p>
                        </div>
                     </form>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your code here:

```
 <div class="well col-sm-4" align="center">
```

With this (you can also isolate the style in a CSS class):

```
<div class="well col-sm-4" style="margin:auto; float:none;">
```